# ui.bootstrap.buttons with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

There seems to be a problem converting ui.bootstrap.buttons to be used with ng-repeat. The ui.bootstrap.buttons example and documentation is here: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Bascially the default example works nicely: http://plnkr.co/edit/2O81y57GtfP6EPNH9qYa?p=preview

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="radioModel" btn-radio="'Left'">Left</label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="radioModel" btn-radio="'Middle'">Middle</label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="radioModel" btn-radio="'Right'">Right</label>
</div>
```

But when it's converted the use ng-repeat, it breaks: http://plnkr.co/edit/nzx1VTGN4Q59JlFCU53V?p=preview

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <label ng-repeat="test in ['Left', 'Middle', 'Right']" class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="radioModel" btn-radio="'{{test}}'">{{test}}</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try

```
<label ng-repeat="test in ['Left', 'Middle', 'Right']" btn-radio="test" class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="radio.model">
```

instead of

`btn-radio="'{{test}}'"`

On top of this `ng-repeat` is creating a new scope so you need to account for this as well. Here is a working plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/h5e5OgFCqv28MPy4tEaM?p=preview

Comment: Cumbersome that it works in your plunk. `uib-button-radio`. It does not change the model's value when using `ng-repeat` in my plunk. 
http://plnkr.co/edit/L4gRDqhvuUKDl9NbpIR6?p=preview
I needed to take: `$parent.model`.

Answer (score 1):

In the end after some testing I got it working using ng-class for initial selected value and own ng-click handler that changes the selected button

HTML-code for the buttons:

```
  <div class="btn-group">
     <button ng-repeat="(timelineIndex, timeline) in timelines" ng-click="selectTimeline(timeline)" ng-class="{active: timeline.name === selectedTimeline.name}" class="btn btn-primary">
        {{timeline.name}}
     </button>
  </div>
```

in controller:

```
  $scope.selectTimeline = function(activeTimeline) {
     $scope.selectedTimeline = activeTimeline;
  };
```